# Asp.net Master-Detail object in view not maching entirely with the view model in actionresult

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, razor

i'm trying to pass an object from an mvc view to an action result with Ajax. But the object that recives the action result doesn't contain the detail object in the main object. Here's the javascript code in the view that post to the action result:

**Javascript on view**

```
        $('#save').click(function () {

            var Details = {
                "Id": "",
                "IdGsm": "",
                "IdCarrier": "",
                "PortName": "",
                "Status": "",
                "CarrierName": ""
            }
            var Carrier = {
                "Id": "",
                "CarrierName": "",
                "MobileNetworkCode": "",
                "MobileCountryCode": "",
                "CountryCode": "",
                "InNetworkCost": "",
                "OutNetworkCost":""
            }
            var Encoding = {
                "Id": "",
                "Description":""
            }

            var GsmViewModel = {
                "Id": "0",
                "Nombre": "0",
                "Ip": "0",
                "Puerto": "",
                "Usuario": "",
                "Password": "",
                "IdEncoding": "",
                "Estado": "",
                "Modelo": "",
                "Details": [],
                "Carrier": [],
                "Encoding": []
            }

            GsmViewModel.Encoding.push(Encoding);
            GsmViewModel.Carrier.push(Carrier);

            GsmViewModel.Id = 0;
            GsmViewModel.Nombre = $('#nombre').val();
            GsmViewModel.Ip = $('#ip').val();
            GsmViewModel.Puerto = $('#puerto').val();
            GsmViewModel.Usuario = $('#usuario').val();
            GsmViewModel.Password = $('#password').val();
            GsmViewModel.IdEncoding = $('#encoding option:selected').val();
            GsmViewModel.Estado = 1;
            GsmViewModel.Modelo = $('#modelo').val();

            var oTable = $('#dt').dataTable().fnGetData();
            for (var i = 0; i < oTable.length; i++) {


                if ($('h2').text() == "Nuevo GSM Gateway") {
                    Details.Id = $('#Id').val();
                }
                else {
                    Details.Id = 0;
                }
                Details.Id = oTable[i][0];
                Details.IdGsm = oTable[i][1];
                Details.IdCarrier = oTable[i][2];
                Details.CarrierName = oTable[i][3];
                Details.PortName = oTable[i][4];
                Details.Status = oTable[i][5];

                GsmViewModel.Details.push(Details);



            }

            });
            tbl.rows().every(function () {
                var data = this.data();

                Details.Id = 0;
                Details.IdGsm = 0;
                Details.IdCarrier = data[2];
                Details.CarrierName = data[3];
                Details.PortName = data[4];
                Details.Status = data[5];

                GsmViewModel.Details.push(Details);
            });

           //Ajax call to the controller, here the GsmViewModel is correctly fulfilled.

            $.ajax({
                url: '/Gsm/SaveGsm',
                data: JSON.stringify(GsmViewModel),
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json;',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (result) {

                    if (result.Success == "1") {
                        //do some things
                    }
                    else {
                        alert(result.ex);
                    }
                }
            });

        });
```

Here's the code in the action result and the model, while debugging the action result, i can see that the properties in the main object are correctly assigned, but the detail list is empty, even though in the view i can see that the object is correctly fulfilled. Some how in the middle the details are getting lost. My best guessing is that the object doesn't match but i been checking the structure of the model and the object and they match.

**Action result**

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult  SaveGsm(GsmViewModel  gsmConfig)
    {

        //do some stuff with the model, the problem here is that the model doesn't contain the details
        return RedirectToAction("ListaGsm", "Gsm");
    }
```

**View Model**

```
public class GsmViewModel
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Nombre { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Dirección IP")]
    public string Ip { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Puerto")]
    public string Puerto { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Usuario")]
    public string Usuario { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Contraseña")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Encoding")]
    public Nullable<int> IdEncoding { get; set; }



    public Nullable<bool> Estado { get; set; }

    public string Modelo { get; set; }

    public List<GsmDetail> Details { get; set; }
    public List<Carrier> Carrier { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Encoding> Encoding { get; set; }
}
```

Thank you in advance, and sorry for my english and my code, i'm a newbie on javascript....

Comment: try without stringify data: JSON.stringify(GsmViewModel), and provide a contentType: application/json

Comment: I remove the JSON.stringify as you suggest and i'm already providing the contentType, no luck though....

Comment: can you check the request headers in Network to check data is posted properly? and/or add [FromBody] in your action method